# How to instruct docker or docker-compose to automatically build image specified in FROM

Tags: docker

When processing a Dockerfile, how do I instruct docker build to build the image specified in FROM locally using another Dockerfile if it is not already available?

Here's the context. I have a large Dockerfile that starts from base Ubuntu image, installs Apache, then PHP, then some custom configuration on top of that. Whether this is a good idea is another point, let's assume the build steps cannot be changed. The problem is, every time I change anything in the config, everything has to be rebuilt from scratch, and this takes a while.

I would like to have a hierarchy of Dockerfiles instead:

- my-apache : based on stock Ubuntu
- my-apache-php: based on my-apache
- final: based on my-apache-php

The first two images would be relatively static and can be uploaded to dockerhub, but I would like to retain an option to build them locally as part of the same build process. Only one container will exist, based on the final image. Thus, putting all three as "services" in docker-compose.yml is not a good idea.

The only solution I can think of is to have a manual build script that for each image checks whether it is available on Dockerhub or locally, and if not, invokes docker build.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: Perhaps you could have an `.env` file with versions for your images which will be updated when you push your images to Docker Hub, and you can use `FROM my-apache:${MY_APACHE_VERSION}` in your PHP image, for example. That way if you don't have that image locally, it will be fetched from Hub. You even have the flexibility to build `my-apache-php` image without rebuilding `my-apache` image. But with this approach, you need to have up to 3 `build` commands if you build everything _from scratch_, which might be a downside.

Comment: Ohh, this could be long.. The short answer is: unlike `docker-compose`, `docker` won't build images if it can't find them. The somewhat longer answer is, from my experience the best option is to use `ARG`'s in the `Dockerfile`'s that you update as part of the release process, make sure to push the images and always `--pull` during builds.

Comment: I am not so much worried about the versioning, I am concentrating on the automated build. I created a script that first checks the image locally, then tries to pull it from dockerhub, and if none of that worked, builds it. I hoped there is more elegant solution though

Answer (score 0):

I have found this article on automatically detecting dependencies between docker files and building them in proper order:
https://philpep.org/blog/a-makefile-for-your-dockerfiles

Actual makefile from Philippe's git repo provides even more functionality:
https://github.com/philpep/dockerfiles/blob/master/Makefile